# Остановка работы стороннего сервиса?

Tags: android, android-service

Скажите как можно, из своего приложения отследить и приостановить работу сервиса, который использует передачу сигнала на динамик (то есть, к примеру, воспроизводит какой-либо аудиофайл, а в своем приложении я планирую задействовать динамик и тот самый микрофон. Через ActivityManager я могу получить список всех запущенных сервисов:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_CERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningService(50);
```

но как из этого списка достать тот самый и приостановить его работу. Или тут нужен другой подход?

Comment: хоть то что выделаете, тоже возможно сделать подругому канеш, но думаю вам нужен стандартный принцип захвата аудиофокуса. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus
Вам необходимо переформулировать вопрос и пояснить сейчас на него ответить невозможно

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не знал про аудиофокус